# Is it possible to import or sync dynaTrace monitoring data to any NoSQL store?

Tags: .net, data-import, dynatrace, nosql

We use dynatrace for monitoring and it generates a lot of monitoring data. I did not find an explicit way to have this imported to local data stores. Has anyone had experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace stores all this data in its own Session Storage (file system) as well as in the so called Performance Warehouse (SQL Storage). Both storage systems can be accessed via the Web Interface or via the Dynatrace Rich Client.
You can also extract this data through REST or use the Live Data Feed option to push data out to e.g: external data source such as Splunk, Elastic Search or any other place.

Here are some links for you to check out
* PureLytics Stream: https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT63/PureLytics+Stream
* Real Time Data Feed: https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/PUB/Real+Time+Business+Transaction+Feed+for+BigData+Analytics
* Real Time Data Feed Github Project: https://github.com/Dynatrace/Dynatrace-Real-Time-Data-Feed-Listener

If you have more questions I also suggest to ask them in our Dynatrace disucssion forum: http://answers.dynatrace.com

Andi